# Session replication exception in Jboss 7 with struts token interceptor in struts2.3.16.3

Tags: jboss, struts2, token, interceptor

I am getting following exception in JBOSS7 if the Struts2 action is configured with struts2 token session interceptor. JBOSS7 is configured in cluster mode.

```
18:04:30,419 ERROR [org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction]
(http-/10.103.36.134:12080-12) ISPN000111: afterCompletion() failed for
SynchronizationAdapter{localTransaction=LocalTransaction{remoteLockedNodes=null,
isMarkedForRollback=false, lockedKeys=null, backupKey Locks=null,
topologyId=26, isFromStateTransfer=false}
org.infinispan.transaction.synchronization.SyncLocalTransaction@97}
org.infinispan. transaction.synchronization.SynchronizationAdapter@b6:
org.infinispan.CacheException: Could not commit.
        at org.infinispan.transaction.synchronization.SynchronizationAdapter.afterCompletion(SynchronizationAdapter.java:83)
        at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.notifyAfterCompletion(DummyTransaction.java:285)
        at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.runCommitTx(DummyTransaction.java:334)
        at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.commit(DummyTransaction.java:91)
        at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyBaseTransactionManager.commit(DummyBaseTransactionManager.java:102)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.web.impl.TransactionBatchingManager.endBatch(TransactionBatchingManager.java:75)
        at org.jboss.as.web.session.DistributableSessionManager.processSessionRepl(DistributableSessionManager.java:1527)
[jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.session.DistributableSessionManager.storeSession(DistributableSessionManager.java:865)
[jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.session.InstantSnapshotManager.snapshot(InstantSnapshotManager.java:47)
[jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.handleRequest(ClusteredSessionValve.java:142)
[jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:99)
[jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.session.JvmRouteValve.invoke(JvmRouteValve.java:92)
[jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.session.LockingValve.invoke(LockingValve.java:64)
[jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
[jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:559)
[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51] Caused by: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
        at org.infinispan.transaction.TransactionCoordinator.handleCommitFailure(TransactionCoordinator.java:224)
        at org.infinispan.transaction.TransactionCoordinator.commit(TransactionCoordinator.java:177)
        at org.infinispan.transaction.synchronization.SynchronizationAdapter.afterCompletion(SynchronizationAdapter.java:81)
        ... 22 more
```

struts.xml:

```
<interceptor-stack name="tokenSessionStack">
                <!-- <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession"/> -->
                <interceptor-ref name="roseStack" />
            </interceptor-stack>
```

I am not seeing above exception if I commented tokenSession interceptor.

> Edit: Looks like struts token session interceptor is giving this kind of exception if the project is implemented with combination of Struts2 + Spring3. Does any body faced session replication problem with this combination?

Comment: A `tokenSession` interceptor has nothing to do with transactions.

Comment: I think the `TokenInterceptor` is adding non-serializable objects to the session. See similar issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-2803

Comment: @RomanC But I am seeing this error only on enabling struts session token interceptor.

Comment: @FedericoSierra yes,Looks like TokenInterceptor is trying to put DefaultActionInvocation object which contains many non-serializable objects.Our project is using struts2+spring3 aop +spring3 security.

Comment: Verify that you have the correct version of `xwork-core.jar`